# Date difference java implement with wrong output

Tags: java, date

I'm currently doing a date difference function and in this scenario, I haven't added the function for leap years but it tends to me that even the date difference for not leap year output is different from the actual date difference by 5 to 8 days depending on the date.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Date_Difference {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);     
        int d1 = myObj.nextInt();
        int m1 = myObj.nextInt();
        int y1 = myObj.nextInt();
        int d2 = myObj.nextInt();
        int m2 = myObj.nextInt();
        int y2 = myObj.nextInt();
        System.out.println(get_Difference(d1,m1,y1,d2,m2,y2));
    }

    static int get_Difference(int d1, int m1, int y1, int d2, int m2, int y2 ) { 
        int n1 = y1 * 365 + d1; 
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < m1 - 1; i++) { 
            n1 += monthDays_notleapyear[i]; 
        } 
        int n2 = y2 * 365 + d2; 
        for (i = 0; i < m2 - 1; i++) { 
            n2 += monthDays_notleapyear[i]; 
        } 
        return Math.abs(n2 - n1); 
    } 
     static int monthDays_notleapyear[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 }; 
}
```

input: d1= 22 12 1999
d2= 31 01 2019
output: 6975 days
actual output: 6980 days

Comment: What is your input ? What is your expected result and what do you get instead? What do you think is ging wrong?

Comment: input: d1= 22 12 1999 d2= 31 01 2019 output: 6975 days actual output: 6980 days

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt i think there is some problem with how my for loop is using the month in days arrays

Comment: There were 5 leap days between those two dates. Your answer is off by 5. So account for leap years and you should be good to go.

Comment: mypetlion is right - you said yourself that you haven't implemented leap years yet, but you are using a time range that includes leap years. Don't do that until you have implemented leap years; before that, only test with time ranges that don't include leap years.

Comment: @mypetlion Well spotted. You can post that as an answer if you want.

Comment: @JackPuthichak If this is a programming exercise, it’s a good one. If this is for production code, don’t code your own date math. Instead use `LocalDate` and `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()`.

Comment: Tip for [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): just write `System.out.println(get_Difference(22, 12, 1999, 31, 1, 2019));` in your code. That the input really comes from the keyboard doesn’t seem to contribute to explaining which problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1:**

If you can use Java Date API, with Java 8, you can do this very easily.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Date_Difference {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(1999, 12, 22), LocalDate.of(2019, 01, 31));

        System.out.println(daysBetween);

    }

}
```

**Option 2:**
If you are not supposed to use Java Date API, then below is an indirect way to calculate.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FSD {

    static int monthDays_notleapyear[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        int d1 = myObj.nextInt();
        int m1 = myObj.nextInt();
        int y1 = myObj.nextInt();
        int d2 = myObj.nextInt();
        int m2 = myObj.nextInt();
        int y2 = myObj.nextInt();

        long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDate.of(y1, m1, d1), LocalDate.of(y2, m2, d2));

        System.out.println("Using Java Date: " + daysBetween);
        get_Difference(d1, m1, y1, d2, m2, y2);
    }

    static int get_Difference(int d1, int m1, int y1, int d2, int m2, int y2) {
        // int n1 = y1 * 365 + d1;

        int yearDiff = y2 - y1 - 1;

        int totalDays = yearDiff * 365;

        int numberOfLeapDays = numberOfLeapYearBetween(y1, y2);

        // Check if (m1 == 2 and d1 <=29 ) or if m1 == 1, increment by 1.
        if ((m1 <= 2 && d1 <= 29) || m1 == 1) {

            boolean isStartLeapYear = isLeapYear(y1);
            if (isStartLeapYear) {
                numberOfLeapDays++;
            }
        }

        // Check if m2 is greater than 3. If yes, check if leap year, increment by 1.
        if (m2 >= 3) {
            boolean isEndLeapYear = isLeapYear(y2);
            if (isEndLeapYear) {
                numberOfLeapDays++;
            }
        }

        int remainingDays = 0;
        for (int i = m1; i <= 12; i++) {

            if (i == m1) {
                remainingDays = remainingDays + (monthDays_notleapyear[i - 1] - d1);
            } else {

                remainingDays = remainingDays + monthDays_notleapyear[i - 1];
            }
        }

        for (int i = m2; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i == m2) {
                remainingDays = remainingDays + d2;
            } else {
                remainingDays = remainingDays + monthDays_notleapyear[i - 1];
            }
        }

        totalDays = totalDays + numberOfLeapDays + remainingDays;

        System.out.println("Total Days: " + totalDays);

        return totalDays;
    }

    private static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {

        boolean leap = false;

        if (year % 4 == 0) {
            if (year % 100 == 0) {
                // year is divisible by 400, hence the year is a leap year
                if (year % 400 == 0)
                    leap = true;
                else
                    leap = false;
            } else
                leap = true;
        } else
            leap = false;

        return leap;

    }

    /**
     * Get Number of Leap Years excluding startYear and endYear.
     * 
     * @param startYear
     * @param endYear
     * @return
     */
    private static int numberOfLeapYearBetween(int startYear, int endYear) {

        int counter = 0;
        while (startYear < endYear - 1) {
            startYear++;
            boolean isLeapYear = isLeapYear(startYear);
            if (isLeapYear) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;

    }

}
```

Comment: Those are two good options in that each has its place. I more read the question as a why the questioner’s code didn’t give the desired result, and you are pretty far from answering that. It could be me reading the question the wrong way, though, it’s not clear at all.

Comment: @ole, Thank you for pointing that out. I should have answered that as well but it was pointed out by *mypetlion* in the comments. So I just wrote the program to correct it.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and solution guys